# Integer to hexadecimal string

Tags: format, ceylon

I know how to write hexadecimal literal integers (`#A3`) in Ceylon. I also know how to parse hexadecimal integers in Ceylon.

```
Integer? integer = parseInteger("A3", 16);
print(integer.string); // 163
```

How do I go the other way, get the hexadecimal string representation of an integer?

Comment: Interestingly, I also had to figure this out when answering [your recent question about crypto functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49717005/600500) :-)

Comment: By the way, you can omit the `.string` when using `print(...)` ... it accepts an Object, and will apply `.string` on it anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Integer.parse`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Integer.type.html#parse) and [`Integer.format`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Integer.type.html#format) functions. They both take a radix, which can be used to generate the string of an integer using an arbitrary base (16 for hexadecimal). By default `formatInteger` generates the string with lowercase letters. Use the `uppercased` property on the string if you want the uppercase version.

```
Integer|ParseException integer = Integer.parse("A3", 16);
assert(is Integer integer);
print(Integer.format(integer, 16)); // a3
print(Integer.format(integer, 16).uppercased); // A3
```

Note that `format` is not an instance method of `Integer`; it is a static method, so you can't do `integer.format(16)`.

Also, note that `parse` returns a `ParseException` on failure rather than `Null` so that there is more information in that failing case.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Both the `parseInteger` and `formatInteger` functions are deprecated since static methods were added, use the `Integer.format` function instead.**

Use the [`formatInteger`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.0.0/module-doc/index.html#parseInteger) function.

```
Integer? integer = parseInteger("A3", 16);
assert(exists integer);
print(formatInteger(integer, 16)); // a3
```

Comment: Why do you have two answers saying basically the same? Could you delete one and incorporate the content into the other?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann They seem like different answers to me. One is "use top-level `formatInteger`", the other is "use static method `Integer.format`. I'll edit them to remove any redundant information.